# XML::LibXML changing character entity from hex to decimal

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

How can I stop Perl
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)
from changing special characters from decimal to hex, like `&#xA` to `&#10`?

#### Perl code

```
use XML::LibXML;

open my $fh, '<', $File;
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => $fh);
open (my $fh, '>', $File) or die $!;
print $fh $doc;
close $fh;
```

A third party tool(.net based) and Perl script needs to deal with same XML file.
XML generated by third party tools contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
<type sRemark="30 minutes.&#xA;&#xA;"/>
</content>
```

But, when Perl script try to update the same file it changes to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
<type sRemark="30 minutes.&#10;&#10;"/>
</content>
```

How can I maintain the same content.

Comment: You probably can't change this. If the syntax of your XML is significant then you're not using it properly.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that produces hex character entities. Please show how you are seeing this unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

When parsing a document, *libxml2* loses the information whether a numeric character reference was provided in decimal or hex. For any sane application, it shouldn't matter which representation is chosen. But since hexadecimal character references happen to be the [canonical representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n/#ProcessingModel), you could try to serialize with [`toStringC14N`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod#toStringC14N).

```
print $doc->toStringC14N; # Will output &#xA;
```

Note that this will normalize other parts of the XML document as well, which may or may not be what you need. Also see the documentation for other canonization methods and options.

Answer (score 0):

The string `&#xA` would be encoded as `&amp;#xA` in XML. `XML::LibXML` will automatically encode it. Printing the XML as a serialized string will yield the encoded character. To print the decoded character, use the `getAttribute` method.

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');
my $string = '&#xA';
my $node = $doc->createElement('Element');
$node->setAttribute('attr', $string);

print $node->toString."\n"; # prints <Element attr="&amp;#xA"/>
print $node->getAttribute('attr')."\n"; # prints &#xA
```

Note that if your string were in the text content part of the element, you would use `$node->textContent` instead.